# Azure Application Insights integration with GraphQL API - HotChocolate Framework

Tags: .net, azure, azure-application-insights, hotchocolate

Is there any way to integrate Azure App Insights with Hotchoclate graphql framework? Currently, there are multiple ways of hacking this together.

What is the best way to get everything into app insights broken down by query in app insights just like you would with a REST api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone is struggling out there, answering my own, as I had to solve this for a recent app I was building.

In HC you need to hook into the diagnostic event listener to get a handle on the pipeline and from there you can hook into the various events and log telemetry.  Key thing here is to make sure you differentiate the query with the query name so it comes out properly in app insights other wise everything will be on the /graphql endpoint

```
public class AppInsightsDiagnosticEventListener : ExecutionDiagnosticEventListener
{
    private readonly TelemetryClient _telemetryClient;

    public AppInsightsDiagnosticEventListener(TelemetryClient telemetryClient) => _telemetryClient = telemetryClient;

    public override IDisposable ExecuteRequest(IRequestContext context)
    {
        var httpContext = GetHttpContextFrom(context);
        if (httpContext == null)
            return EmptyScope;

        //During debugging every playground action will come here so we want this while debugging
        #if DEBUG
        if (context.Request.OperationName == "IntrospectionQuery")
            return EmptyScope;
        #endif

        //Create a new telemetry request
        var operationPath = $"{context.Request.OperationName ?? "UnknownOperation"} - {context.Request.QueryHash}";
        var requestTelemetry = new RequestTelemetry()
        {
            Name = $"/graphql{operationPath}",
            Url = new Uri(httpContext.Request.GetUri().AbsoluteUri + operationPath),
        };

        requestTelemetry.Context.Operation.Name = $"POST /graphql/{operationPath}";
        requestTelemetry.Context.Operation.Id = GetOperationIdFrom(httpContext);
        requestTelemetry.Context.Operation.ParentId = GetOperationIdFrom(httpContext);
        requestTelemetry.Context.User.AuthenticatedUserId = httpContext.User.Identity?.Name ?? "Not authenticated";

        if (context.Request.Query != null)
            requestTelemetry.Properties.Add("GraphQL Query", context.Request.Query.ToString());

        var operation = _telemetryClient.StartOperation(requestTelemetry);
        return new ScopeWithEndAction(() => OnEndRequest(context, operation));
    }

    private void OnEndRequest(IRequestContext context, IOperationHolder<RequestTelemetry> operation)
    {
        var httpContext = GetHttpContextFrom(context);
        operation.Telemetry.Success = httpContext.Response.StatusCode is >= 200 and <= 299;
        operation.Telemetry.ResponseCode = httpContext.Response.StatusCode.ToString();

        if (context.Exception != null)
        {
            operation.Telemetry.Success = false;
            operation.Telemetry.ResponseCode = "500";
            _telemetryClient.TrackException(context.Exception);
        }

        if (context.ValidationResult?.HasErrors ?? false)
        {
            operation.Telemetry.Success = false;
            operation.Telemetry.ResponseCode = "400";
        }

        if (context.Result?.Errors != null)
        {
            foreach (var error in context.Result.Errors)
            {
                if (error.Exception != null)
                {
                    operation.Telemetry.Success = false;
                    _telemetryClient.TrackException(error.Exception);
                }
            }
        }

        _telemetryClient.StopOperation(operation);
    }

    public override void RequestError(IRequestContext context, Exception exception)
    {
        _telemetryClient.TrackException(exception);
        base.RequestError(context, exception);
    }

    public override void ValidationErrors(IRequestContext context, IReadOnlyList<IError> errors)
    {
        foreach (var error in errors)
        {
            _telemetryClient.TrackTrace("GraphQL validation error: " + error.Message, SeverityLevel.Warning);
        }
        base.ValidationErrors(context, errors);
    }

    private HttpContext GetHttpContextFrom(IRequestContext context)
    {
        // This method is used to enable start/stop events for query.
        if (!context.ContextData.ContainsKey("HttpContext"))
            return null;

        return context.ContextData["HttpContext"] as HttpContext;
    }

    private string GetOperationIdFrom(HttpContext context) => context.TraceIdentifier;
}

internal class ScopeWithEndAction : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Action _disposeAction;

    public ScopeWithEndAction(Action disposeAction) => _disposeAction = disposeAction;

    public void Dispose() => _disposeAction.Invoke();
}
```

**And in startup**

```
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
        services.AddGraphQLServer()
            .AddDiagnosticEventListener<AppInsightsDiagnosticEventListener>((sp) => new AppInsightsDiagnosticEventListener(sp.GetService<TelemetryClient>()));
```